# Buscar somente o menor número de cada letra

Tags: sql-server

Como faço para buscar somente o menor número de cada letra, no Sql server?

Minha tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Resultado esperado:*

```
A - 1

B - 2

C - 1

D - 1

E - 3
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar a função `Min`com a função de agregação `Group By`.

Usei o Script abaixo para testes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TesteLetra](
    [letra] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [numero] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('A',1)
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('B',2)
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('C',1)
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('D',1)
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('D',2)
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('D',3)
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('E',3)
insert into TesteLetra (letra,numero) values
('E',4)
```

*E minha consulta foi a seguinte:*

```
select letra,Min(numero) ValorMinimo from TesteLetra
Group By letra
```

*Resultado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa é mais mole que tirar doce de criança. :)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: @Brupikk que bom que pude ajudar :), não esqueça de marcá-la como correta pois pode ajudar outras pessoas também.

Comment: @Marconi sem fala que ele ganha 2 postos por aceita :)