# Group by com erro no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia, gostaria de sabe o por que minha query SQL não esta dando certo, estou usando o SQL Server 2008 e meu `GROUP BY` esta dando errado. Já verifiquei e o nome das tabelas estão corretas e estão preenchidas corretamente.

Código:

```
SELECT categoria, nome_categoria
FROM tabela_teste.dbo.teste
WHERE vigencia = '2016-04'
GROUP BY categoria
ORDER BY nome_categoria;
```

Erro:

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Se você rodar o comando select categoria from tabela_teste.dbo.teste where vigencia = '2016-04' group by categoria order by nome_categoria; funciona?

Comment: Se rodar desta forma ele continua a não funcionar, o erro do group by continua. Mas se eu retirar  o nome_tabela e o order by ele funciona. Entretanto eu preciso usar o group by e order by para a minha pesquisar dar certo.

Comment: Poste a estrutura da tabela. Respondi uma pergunta aqui, veja se serve de ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131637/buscar-somente-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-cada-letra/131640#131640

Comment: Olhando em alguns sites todos usam um group by seguido de uma  funções de grupo(sum, max...), no meu caso não preciso da função de grupo. Mas como disse sem o order by o comando funciona funciona, a minha tabela esta preenchida corretamente senão o comando não teria funcionado, cheguei a pensar que o group by trabalha somente com funções de agrupamento.

Comment: Olhei o link que vc me enviou, grato como disse acima lá vc usa a função de agrupamento, tente colocar o order by no seu comando e veja se ele funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 8):

Todos os campos do select tem de estar agrupados ou contidos na clausula GROUP BY ou agrupados por SUM, MIN, MAX

```
 select categoria, nome_categoria from tabela_teste.dbo.teste 
 where vigencia =   '2016-04' group by categoria, nome_categoria 
 order by nome_categoria;
```

Abaixo alguns selects que estão sintaticamente corretos:

```
select cdfilial, cdlocal, dslocal  from minhatabela group by cdfilial, cdlocal, dslocal

select min( cdfilial ), cdlocal, dslocal  from minhatabela group by cdlocal, dslocal

select min( cdfilial ), max( cdlocal ), min( dslocal )  from minhatabela

select sum( cdfilial ), max( cdlocal ), min( dslocal ) from minhatabela
```

Você é que vai determinar como quer agrupar os seus dados e qual o tipo de agrupamento que deseja.

Comment: Poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: Essa característica é valida somente para o sqlServer 2008?

Comment: Não. Isso funciona em todos os bancos que conheço. SQLServer, Oracle, Firebird, Sqlite, MySql.

Comment: Alterei meu código aqui com sua sugestão e funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda. Gostaria de saber se essa característica persiste em outras versões do sqlServer?

Comment: Sim. Todas as versões.

Comment: @fernando Este é o padrão SQL e é suportado por todos os bancos. Reginaldo, o MySql, além de suportar o padrão, também aceita essa pira de deixar campos de fora do group by e também sem nenhuma função de agregação, daí ele decide o que fazer. Eu paritcularmente considero isso mais um bug que uma feature, pois você pode ter deixado campo de fora por engano e ele não te avisa - simplesmente dá o resultado que você não esperava.

Comment: @Caffé Eu testei no MySql sem o group by em um dos campos e ele simplesmente agrupou pelos outros e ignorou aquele que não estava contido. As vezes isso também é bem vindo. De qualquer forma tem de ficar atento.