# Listar somente a maior faixa etária?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou tentando fazer um comparativo por idade para listar somente a idade correspondente a sua faixa etaria.  *Ex:* 20 anos faixa etaria de  0 a 43.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    U.USS_CODIGO,
    t.con_codigo,
        t.CON_SEQUENCIA,
        t.PLA_NUMERO,
        t.PDT_CODIGO,
        t.PPC_DT_VIGENCIA, 
    t.PPC_IDADE_MIN, 
        t.PPC_VAL_MENSALIDADE,
    u.uss_fat_idade,

  CASE WHEN (t.PPC_IDADE_MIN >= 0 and t.PPC_IDADE_MIN <= 43)THEN ' 0 A 43 '
              WHEN (t.PPC_IDADE_MIN >= 44 and t.PPC_IDADE_MIN <= 48)THEN  '44 A 48'
              WHEN (t.PPC_IDADE_MIN >= 49 and t.PPC_IDADE_MIN <= 53)THEN  '49 A 53'
              WHEN (t.PPC_IDADE_MIN >= 54 and t.PPC_IDADE_MIN <= 58)THEN  '54 A 58'
              WHEN (t.PPC_IDADE_MIN >=59) THEN '  maior de 59 '
     END AS FAIXA_ETARIA



FROM preco_produto_contrato t, contratante c, USUARIO U
        WHERE t.PPC_DT_EXC IS NULL 

        AND c.con_dt_exc IS NULL
        AND t.pla_numero in (105)
    AND U.CON_CODIGO  = C.CON_CODIGO
        AND t.con_codigo = c.con_codigo
    AND U.Uss_Dt_Exc is null
        AND t.con_sequencia = c.con_sequencia
        ORDER BY t.con_codigo
```

Comment: Qual resultado você obtêm?

Comment: obtenho uma lista de pessoas com as suas devidas mensalidades, e as faixas sao as taxas de reajustes. porem esta trazendo todas as faixas e todas as idades  e nao somente a idade e a faixa dele

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer;

Comment: Tem como exibir um print do resultado na sua pergunta? E como gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: Pelo que entende no titulo da pergunta você quer a maior faixa etaria do resultado, seria isso? Seria mais ou menos como essa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131637/buscar-somente-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-cada-letra/131640#131640. Diferença que você deve usar O MAX.

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar uss_fat_idade no CASE no lugar de PPC_IDADE_MIN ?! mas para mim ao menos ficou nebuloso ...

Comment: 2021235 3131 0 105 95 01/12/2008 0 141,07 85  0 A 43 
2021235 3131 0 105 95 01/12/2008 44 269,29 85 44 A 48
2021235 3131 0 105 95 01/12/2008 49 325,47 85 49 A 53
2021235 3131 0 105 95 01/12/2008 54 435,05 85 54 A 58
2021235 3131 0 105 95 01/12/2008 59 508,71 85   maior de 59 
2021235 3131 0 105 96 01/12/2008 0 193,44 85  0 A 43 
2021235 3131 0 105 96 01/12/2008 44 369,25 85 44 A 48
2021235 3131 0 105 96 01/12/2008 49 446,27 85 49 A 53
2021235 3131 0 105 96 01/12/2008 54 608,94 85 54 A 58
2021740 3131 0 105 95 01/12/2008 44 269,29 59 44 A 48

Comment: seria  isso mesmo compara todas as idades  e listar  o PPC_IDADE_MIN  que corresponde a idade  que esta no  uss_fat_idade

Comment: SELECT ...

  CASE WHEN u.uss_fat_idade >= 0 and u.uss_fat_idade <= 43)THEN ' 0 A 43 '
              WHEN (u.uss_fat_idade >= 44 and u.uss_fat_idade <= 48)THEN  '44 A 48'
              WHEN (u.uss_fat_idade >= 49 and u.uss_fat_idade <= 53)THEN  '49 A 53'
              WHEN (u.uss_fat_idade >= 54 and u.uss_fat_idade <= 58)THEN  '54 A 58'
              WHEN (u.uss_fat_idade >=59) THEN '  maior de 59 '
     END AS FAIXA_ETARIA

...

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer uma store procedure para  resolver esse problema

Comment: Não entendi aonde a SP entraria na história. @Alan Darold