# INNER JOIN com ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, order-by

Em *MYSQL* tenho duas tabelas, produto e produto_foto.

Na tabela produto_foto tem um campo que chama **primeira** que normalmente seu valor é 0. No sistema administrativo do site pode existir a marcação de qual a foto será a primeira (principal) e então esse campo **primeira** fica com o valor 1.

Tabela *Produto:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela *Produto_Foto:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao listar todos os produtos do site, apenas uma foto de cada produto é apresentada. E eu queria que fosse apenas a foto em que o campo **primeira** é igual a *1*.

*Tenho usado o select:*

```
SELECT * FROM produto 
INNER JOIN produto_foto ON produto_foto.idproduto = produto.id
GROUP BY produto.id
ORDER BY produto.id DESC, primeira_foto.primeira DESC
```

*Resultado esperado:*

```
chupeta - fotoX.jpg

caderno - fotoX.jpg

tesoura - foto.jpg (nesse caso não existiu marcação de qual é a foto 1, então pegaria o registro de menor ID da tabela Produto_Foto)
```

Comment: Tente ilustrar suas tabelas com dados e tente adicionar um resultado esperado. Tipo a ilustração dessa pergunta, facilitaria muito na ajuda por uma resposta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131637/buscar-somente-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-cada-letra/131640#131640

Comment: Valeu pela dica @Marconi, editei aqui!

Comment: Dei uma melhorada, nela. Veja como ficou. Acho que assim fica melhor entender @caiocafardo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, tente isso.

```
SELECT p.*, pf.* 
  FROM produto p
 INNER JOIN produto_foto pf ON p.id = pf.idproduto
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT id
                FROM produto_foto 
               WHERE primeira = 1
               UNION
              SELECT MIN(id) AS id
                FROM produto_foto
               GROUP BY idproduto HAVING SUM(primeira) = 0 ) i ON pf.id = i.id
```

Um exemplo para ser executado aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96324/1

Comment: O Resultado que ele deseja não é esse @Emerson.

Comment: @Marconi, só se eu entendi errado. Ao que parece o campo `primeira` é tem o comportamento de um booleano. O @caiocafardo deseja que para cada produto retorne a foto com campo `primeira` = 1, porém nem todos os produtos tem fotos assim. Quando não houver nenhuma foto que se enquadra nessa condição retorna aquela foto do produto que possua o menor ID. Me corrija se entendi errado.

Comment: É isto mesmo @Emerson, porém sua query está trazendo os 2 registros de `chupeta`.

Comment: Não está não, você executou o exemplo que coloquei no texto da resposta?

Comment: Verdade, é isso mesmo que ele quer. +1

Comment: É isso ae! Valeu pela ajuda e preocupação!