# Calcular intervalo de tempo no SQL

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma tabela onde tenho 2 campos horainicio e horaafinal estou querendo pegar os resultados que se encaixa entre os valores inicial e final porem sem sucesso segue o que estou usando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou pegando a hora atual e tentando fazer essa comparacao

```
$horaatual = date("H:i");

  SELECT * FROM programacao WHERE horafinal => '$horaatual' ORDER BY Nid DESC LIMIT 1";
```

alguma sugestao? alterado o codigo

Comment: Em qual formato está o campo horainicio?

Comment: Já [tentou](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) ?

Comment: o campo esta em vachar onde é cadastrado da seguinte forma em texto 11:15 , 15:25 etc

Comment: Você cadastra uma hora por registros? ou varias horas no mesmo?

Comment: cadastro por registro e um sistema de programacao de locutores EX: ID 1 nome= fulano horainicio=12:00 ID2 nome=ciclano horainicio=15:00

Comment: @Marconi  tentei agora utulizar o betwenn porem nao retornou resultados

Comment: @ArsomNolasco aqui tem uma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131637/buscar-somente-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-cada-letra/131640#131640) bem auto Explicativa. Teria como editar uma e colocar no modelo parecido? Digo estrutura, dados e resultados esperados

Comment: Já tentou converter o campo `varchar` para _time_ usando o `hour()` ?`'{$horaatual}' BETWEEN HOUR(horainicio) AND HOUR(horafinal)` ?

Comment: @ArsomNolasco conseguiu?

Comment: sem resultados tambem

Comment: Já considerou alterar os seu campos para um tipo que seja de datas? Fica bem mais fácil para trabalhar.

Answer (score 0):

A sua query inicial está escrita com erros. O correto seria >= e não =>.
O campo no qual contém os valores dos horários deve ser do tipo TIME.
Feito isso, não vejo motivos para o seu código não funcionar.