# "top" com MAX em mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne os 3 maiores salários de funcionários publico, por estado. exemplo que deve retornar:

```
fulano     850 RJ
ciclano    800 RJ
beltrano   700 RJ
joao      1000 SP
maria      900 SP
pedro      200 SP
```

Eu utilizei `MAX` em salario e agrupei por estado, porem, so aparece os maiores salários de cada estado.
Se alguém souber, por favor me ajude.

Comment: `Group by Funcionario, Estado` já tentou?Essa minha [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131637/buscar-somente-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-cada-letra/131640#131640) é muito parecida com o que quer porém ai respondi usando o `Min`

Comment: Veja este link, talvez isso te ajude:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775820/sql-give-me-3-hits-for-each-type-only

Comment: Camila, poste sua tabela e a query que tentou por favor.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tb_funcionarios group by fu_estado ORDER By fu_salario DESC LIMIT 3.
```

o truque é usar o ORDER BY campo DESC por que ele vai orndenar na ordem decrecente e você colocando o LIMIT 3 ele vai exibir só os 3 primeiros