# SQL - Dúvida em uma query

Tags: sql, firebird

Graças a ajuda do Motta consegui chegar em uma query satisfatória mas esbarrei em uma outra dúvida pois, necessito que liste apenas o menor registro por `cod`, e que conte a quantidade da coluna `menorregistro` por nome.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Segue o retorno da query para exemplificação:

[image: Imagem do retorno]

Ou seja, necessito que liste apenas as linhas com a coluna MenorRegistro = 558, 896 e 1321.
E que conte o MenorRegistro por nome ficando dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Não necessito da coluna DT_ATE e nem que liste qual foi o menor registro quero apenas que conte quantos menores registros cada nome teve, deixei as colunas apenas para exemplificar melhor o problema.

Segue a query:

```
select b.pront as cod, 
       d.nome,
       b.dt_ate,
       min(case when b.dt_ate between '19.12.2015' and '08.01.2016' then b.reg else null end) menorRegistro
            from recadate b
            inner join tbcbopro c on b.crm=c.cod
            inner join tbprofis d on c.id_tbprofis=d.id
              where b.conv between :ConvInicial and :ConvFinal
              and b.unidade between :Unidade_inicial and :Unidade_final
              and b.pront in (111811, 210313, 395415) 
group by d.nome, b.pront, b.reg, b.dt_ate 
having min(case when b.dt_ate between '19.12.2015' and '08.01.2016' then b.reg else null end) is not null
```

Comment: Seria algo do tipo? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131637/buscar-somente-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-cada-letra/131640#131640

Comment: Olá marconi, apenas retirei a dt_ate e está listando corretamente agora como na segunda imagem, mas preciso contar a coluna menorRegistro sendo que essa coluna é uma função agregada min, isso não sei como fazer já pesquisei muito..

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2:**

```
SELECT cod, nome, MIN(menorregistro) AS menorregistro
FROM (
    SELECT
      b.pront AS cod,
      d.nome,
      b.dt_ate,
      MIN(IIF(b.dt_ate BETWEEN '2015-12-19' AND '2016-01-08', b.reg, NULL)) AS menorregistro
    FROM recadate b
    INNER JOIN tbcbopro c ON b.crm = c.cod
    INNER JOIN tbprofis d ON c.id_tbprofis = d.id
    WHERE 
      AND b.conv    BETWEEN :ConvInicial     AND :ConvFinal
      AND b.unidade BETWEEN :Unidade_inicial AND :Unidade_final
      AND b.pront   IN (111811, 210313, 395415)
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    HAVING MIN(IIF(b.dt_ate BETWEEN '2015-12-19' AND '2016-01-08', b.reg, NULL)) IS NOT NULL
) GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Não amigo, dessa forma ele pegaria o menor registro por data exemplo:

Answer (score 1):

Usei o with apenas para criar uma tabela e  trabalhar com o select que você já definiu, depois disso apenas realizei um group by cod  e  um count dos menores registros.

```
with tabela as(
 select b.pront as cod,
        d.nome,
        b.dt_ate,
        min(case when b.dt_ate between '19.12.2015' and '08.01.2016' then b.reg else null end) menorRegistro
             from recadate b
             inner join tbcbopro c on b.crm=c.cod
             inner join tbprofis d on c.id_tbprofis=d.id
               where b.conv between :ConvInicial and :ConvFinal
               and b.unidade between :Unidade_inicial and :Unidade_final
               and b.pront in (111811, 210313, 395415)
 group by d.nome, b.pront, b.reg, b.dt_ate
 having min(case when b.dt_ate between '19.12.2015' and '08.01.2016' then b.reg else null end) is not null
)


 select cod
       ,nome
       ,count(menorRegistro)
   from tabela
 group by cod
```

Comment: Fui citado , mas creio que esteja mais que respondido.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um `SubSelect` para fazer isso, a ideia e agrupa seus dados no select interno usando o Min() para pegar o menor valor e depois fazer o `Count()` no select de fora.

Da seguinte forma.

```
select pront, nome, count(b.reg) as menorRegistro 
from (
    select b.pront, d.nome, min(b.reg) menorRegistro
        from recadate b
        inner join tbcbopro c on b.crm=c.cod
        inner join tbprofis d on c.id_tbprofis=d.id
            where b.conv between :ConvInicial and :ConvFinal
            and b.unidade between :Unidade_inicial and :Unidade_final
            and b.pront in (111811, 210313, 395415) 
    group by d.nome, b.pront, b.reg, b.dt_ate 
)subconsulta
group by nome, pront
```