# Como fazer um count no Mysql usando o case ou if?

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando saber como posso fazer uma pesquisa no mysql para saber quantos documentos tenho para analizar com uma condição que se o processo anterior nao estiver liberado ele nao pode contar.

```
SELECT COUNT(`num`),
        CASE  WHEN (`pl_de_manutencao` = 'Liberado' || `pl_de_manutencao` = 'N/A'
            AND `ra_padrao` != 'Liberado' || `ra_padrao` != 'N/A') 
        THEN COUNT(`num`) END AS `Count` 
FROM `ind_master_view`
```

algo parecido com esse código.

Comment: Tente [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/147639/edit) e adicionar resultados esperados e sua estrutura de tabela, algo parecido com essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131637/buscar-somente-o-menor-n%C3%BAmero-de-cada-letra/131640#131640).

Comment: já coloquei para agrupar e ele meda os valores, porem que eu preciso do valor total

Answer (score 1):

Se é o que estou entendendo, você tem que usar o COUNT() antes do case com incremento de 1 caso a condição seja verdadeira .

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE  WHEN (pl_de_manutencao = 'Liberado' || pl_de_manutencao = 'N/A' 
                        AND ra_padrao != 'Liberado' || ra_padrao != 'N/A') 
                    THEN 1  -- caso a condição seja verdadeira .
            END) AS Total
FROM ind_master_view
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]